# Unable to run Anaconda on Mac 10.11

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

In this tutorial (3.16), after downloading and then running graphical installer from from main anaconda website and then typing on mac's terminal:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (x86_64)|...
```

However, when I do the same thing, it gives me the following:

```
JOHNMAC:~ Main$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Apr  4 2017, 08:46:44) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more 
information.
```

1. Why not python version 3?
2. Is it actually running Anaconda? It's not displaying Anaconda version like my tutorial's computer does...

For more info...

```
JOHNMAC:~ Main$ python3
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Checking $PATH:

```
JOHNMAC:~ Main$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/Main/anaconda/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Conda info:

```
JOHNMAC:~ Main$ conda info
Current conda install:

           platform : osx-64
      conda version : 4.3.22
   conda is private : False
  conda-env version : 4.3.22
conda-build version : not installed
     python version : 3.6.1.final.0
   requests version : 2.14.2
   root environment : /Users/Main/anaconda  (writable)
default environment : /Users/Main/anaconda
   envs directories : /Users/Main/anaconda/envs
                      /Users/Main/.conda/envs
      package cache : /Users/Main/anaconda/pkgs
                      /Users/Main/.conda/pkgs
       channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                      https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
        config file : /Users/Main/.condarc
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
         user-agent : conda/4.3.22 requests/2.14.2 CPython/3.6.1 Darwin/15.6.0 OSX/10.11.6    
            UID:GID : 501:20
```

Comment: Looks like you've put `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin` before Anaconda

Comment: I just reordered anaconda to be before those. but when i type "python" from mac terminal, i still get information about python version and anaconda doesn't seem to be running.

Comment: weird... i thought i reordered it but changed back to where i was...

Comment: You need to open a brand new terminal after changing the PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing `which python` to see where the python binary is coming from.

Because Unix looks up binaries in PATH order, it will check for python in `/usr/local/bin` first, and use the preinstalled python instead of the python installed by Anaconda at `/Users/Main/anaconda/bin/python`.

To fix this, you can change your PATH order by running:

```
export PATH=/Users/Main/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: I just ran your suggested code and then got the following:

    JOHNMAC:~ Main$ which python
    /usr/local/bin/python

    JOHNMAC:~ Main$ python
    Python 2.7.13 (default, Apr  4 2017, 08:46:44) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)] on 
    darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

I don't think it's still running anaconda?